# how do i connect to server using ror

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `initialize': getaddrinfo: no address a
        from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `open'
        from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `connect'
        from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:48:in `timeout'
        from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:76:in `timeout'
        from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `connect'
        from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:553:in `do_start'
        from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:542:in `start'
        from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:379:in `get_response'
        from ./run2.rb:23:in `get_streams'
        from ./run2.rb:117:in `search_streams'
        from main.rb:19
```

I'm getting this error when I tried to connect to the web server.
Why is it so?

Comment: a stack trace is nice, but can you provide some more background, and perhaps the offending code?

Comment: Its hard to debug issues and errors without code to work from.

Comment: url="http://smruti.com/streams/new" print url print "\n" puts "**********xtracting the data from XML response file................**********\n" xml_data = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url)).body

Comment: For multi-line code or output, please indent by four spaces. For single-line code or output, please have back-ticks around them.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are behind a proxy. `getaddrinfo` is used to resolve DNS Requests - but is the error message really "no address a" ?

[Ruby Documentation of Net::HTTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/classes/Net/HTTP.html) (with examples)

Answer (score 0):

The incomplete error message you're posting is likely "no address associated with hostname", which indicates that wherever you're trying to connect to isn't accessible from where you're at. Since the problem is at `from ./run2.rb:23:in 'get_streams'`, can you print out the address you're trying to connect to and see if it in fact is reachable from your machine?